# playing videos in flash player

Tags: flash, video

i am working on a project. my project needs videos tv( Playing videos flash player).
my reference site is http://www.zooweekly.com.au/zootube/index.htm.

I need that type of flash player.
is it passible to do it. can you guide me plz...

Answer (score 0):

either use flowplayer as mentioned by FractalizeR, or use the flash component "flvplayer". You could also google "free flash player", and you'll probably find something that will suit your needs.